# Multiple dropdown filters interfering with each other

Tags: search, request, query

I have a multiple dropdown filters that lets users pick the category that they want to display results for below. See my previous question [Search entries by location or name](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18523/search-entries-by-location-or-name) for screenshot.

So I have one working, but I need some guidance on how to do the code for the other filters as well, as currently my code for linking up to the second filter is stopping the first filter from working correctly. So clearly I'm doing it wrong.

So I have four dropdown filters, but I'll simplify it to two filters for this example. The filters are named `name="county1"` and `name="development1"` in their respective  tags.

And then I'm using the following to access them:

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('county1') %}
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('development1') %}
{% set queryFilter = craft.categories.group('developments').search(query).order('title asc') %}

{% for category in queryFilter %}

....markup...

{% endfor %}
```

Can someone tell me what i need to do to fix this so that the filters don't interfere with each other?

Comment: Are you trying to filter for a category or entries based on a category selected?  Does your drop-downs contain categories from the group 'developments'?

Comment: The first dropdown holds categories from a category group called counties and the second dropdown holds categories from a category group called developments. The filters themselves are showing the correct data and the first dropdown is creating the right results when selected, but the problem I'm having is that the second dropdown is not outputting the correct results. So I'm assuming the line `{% set query = craft.request.getParam('development1') %}` and possibly that I need to set a second queryFilter row with different name?

Comment: Are you trying to filter by both at the same time or just one filter at a time?

Comment: just one at a time is all I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to filter by one drop-down value at a time then you could use an if statement to check if the passed value is set for each drop-down.  This will only work if each drop-down has an option that is blank or it submits on select so that the other drop-down is not set.

```
{% set query = "" %}
{% if craft.request.getParam('country1') and 
      craft.request.getParam('country1') is not empty %}
    {% set query = craft.request.getParam('country1') %}
{% elseif craft.request.getParam('development1') and 
          craft.request.getParam('development1') is not empty %}
    {% set query = craft.request.getParam('development1') %}
{% endif %}

{% for category in queryFilter %}

....markup...

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Excellent, that has it working, but only if I turn off dev mode as in dev mode it says `Variable "query" does not exist` So is there any ideas how to fix that? If not I can just turn off dev mode.

Comment: I have updated the answer